# Modify internal operations in the function with respect to parameters specified- python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
name  age  city zipcode
 Jon   22  CA   0002
 Raj   34  GG   3454
 ...   ..  ..   ....
 ...   ..  ..   ....
```

I want to write a function **Preprocess(df,[params])** such that the preprocessing should happen only on the columns of the dataframe which will be passed in the params.

for eg.

```
def preprocess(df,params):
    name_list = df['name'].tolist()
    mean_age = df['age'].mean()
    city_list = df['city'].tolist()
    zipcode_list = df['zipcode'].tolist()

    return [name_list, mean_age, city_list, zipcode_list]

result = preprocess(df,['age','city'])
```

What I'm looking for is if I am passing only **age** and **city** i want the preprocessing to happen only for those two columns

```
ie
mean_age = df['age'].mean()
city_list = df['city'].tolist()
```

One way is to use if else/ try-catch

I'm looking for the best approach or a pythonic way of solving this

Comment: I guess you can make a dictionary of lambdas and iterate over params pulling apropriate lambdas. That'll look smart i guess and will be easier to modify.